# How to find changes to a line in jgit?

Tags: git, spring-boot, jgit

I want to find the commit that changed a line using jgit.  I understand jGit does not have a inbuilt git log -L functionality. How would I do this in jGit. I believe I have to parse the log manually. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the JGIT, how can I retrieve the line numbers of added/deleted lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467305/using-the-jgit-how-can-i-retrieve-the-line-numbers-of-added-deleted-lines)

Comment: No, I want the commit history of a specific line, not number of line added between commits.

Comment: Did you try using JGit's `BlameCommand`?